# How to divide for i in arange by a list?

Tags: python, list

I recently got into learning python and Im struggling to solve this puzzle I gave myself: finding prime numbers

i am sure there are more elegant ways, but I would prefer to do it this way to learn how lists and for in range interact.

I have a list of primenumbers:

```
prime_list = [2, 3, 5, 7]
```

and an arange list which checks every odd number:

```
for attempt in arange(9.0, 100.0, 2.0):
```

Now, optimally I would like to do the following operation:

- from prime_list, use all numbers which are >= squareroot of attempt (9 in the first case)
- check if 9 / 2 != int
- check if 9 / 3 != int
- if at least 1 is TRUE, then move to next attempt number which is 11 and repeat steps
- if none true, then break, and print number

So far I could only come up with this code below, where I have to manually enter 2 and then 3 and make the logic check myself...

```
    from numpy import arange
    prime_list = [2, 3, 5, 7]

    for attempt in arange(9.0, 100.0, 2.0):
        prime_check = attempt / 2
        if int(prime_check) != prime_check:
            print(prime_check)
            break
    print(attempt)
```

Thanks for any helps and tips!

Comment: Why are you using `arange()` instead of `range()`, and using floats instead of integers?

Comment: You want `for prime in prime_list:` to try them each.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to use floats or numpy for this.

To test all the primes, use `for prime in prime_list:`. And to test if the number divides exactly, use the modulus operator `%`.

```
prime_list = [2, 3, 5, 7]

for attempt in range(9, 100, 2):
    for prime in prime_list:
        if attempt % prime == 0:
            break
    else:
        print("%d is prime" % attempt)
```

The `else:` block of a `for` loop runs if the loop runs to completion without executing `break`.

Answer (score 1):

```
def isPrime(n):
if n <= 1:
    return False
if n == 2:
    return True
if n % 2 == 0:
    return False

i = 3
while i * i <= n:
    if n % i == 0:
        return False
    i += 2
return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print 'Check prime in range(10000)'
    for i in range(10000):
        if isPrime(i):
            print repr(i) + ' is prime'
```

I'm sure there are so many practices you can do and so many methods are available for this particular problem. But the thing I can give you for start is this practical website which I used it myself last year.
Take a look:
[a practical website for python exercises](http://practicepython.org/)